# How do I manually install vmware tools?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, installation, vmware-player, vmware-tools

I installed UBUNTU with Vmware Player on my Windows 7 system. For some reason Vmware Player cannot get the Vmware Tools files from internet, possibly a connection problem due to firewall limitations. I want to get the Vmware Tools files in compressed format if there is any, and then manually install it. Two questions:
1- Is there a link where i can download Vmware Tools files?
2- How do i install it manually? I'm using Vmware Player on a Windows 7 system. And if i download it, which folder should i unzip the contents? As you know, UBUNTU runs on a virtual disk, and to copy files on this disk i guess i have to use Vmware Tools. But i don't have it already. 
Please help!

Comment: This is not about programming. Try http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here are three steps I used to install the VMWare Tools.  I got the steps from Ubuntu help.

## install kernel headers so modules will work

## needed this on a 10.04 guest running in a Fusion 3 host

apt-get install linux-headers-virtual

## install kernel modules

apt-get install --no-install-recommends open-vm-dkms

## EITHER: install tools for an xorg install

apt-get install open-vm-tools

## OR: a headless install

apt-get install --no-install-recommends open-vm-tools